# Multiprocessing program exits on with warning on KeyboardInterrupt (chunk = read(handle, remaining))

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-3.8

I constantly catch a warning when trying to close my Python program, that uses asyncio and multiprocessing (by [pathos](https://pypi.org/project/pathos/)), via Ctrl + c.

There's a class that's responsible for sending messages via [Telegram bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
class MyAgent:
    def __init__(self, test_mode: bool = False):
        token = settings.env.str('BOT_TOKEN')
        self.updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
        self.bot = Bot(token=token)
        self.chat_id = settings.CHAT_ID
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        self.messagers = []
        self.fetching_tasks = []

        self.test_mode = test_mode

    def register_messagers(self, messagers: list):
        for messager in messagers:
            msgr = messager(self)
            self.messagers.append(msgr)
            # Need to keep fetching task instances alive in the list
            self.fetching_tasks.append(msgr.create_task())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    from pathos import multiprocessing as mp

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", action='store_true')
    ns = parser.parse_args()

    agent = MyAgent(test_mode=ns.test)
    agent.register_messagers([Messager1, Messager2])

    # Start up TG polling in a separate process
    p = mp.ProcessPool(nodes=1)
    # start_polling source code https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/ext/updater.py#L221
    p.pipe(agent.updater.start_polling)

    try:
        tasks = asyncio.gather(*agent.fetching_tasks)
        agent.loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        agent.loop.close()

        # Shut down TG polling
        p.close()
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
    finally:
        print("Bye!")
```

I have a couple of coroutines that run infinitely in an event loop:

```
class Messager1:

    def __init__(self, agent):
        self.agent = agent

    def create_task(self):
        return self.agent.loop.create_task(self._run_forever())

    async def _run_forever(self):
        while True:
            await self.run()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    async def run(self):
            current_time = datetime.now()
            msgs = fetch_messages_from_db(current_time)
            for _ in range(len(msgs)):
                message = "This is coroutine 1"

                if self.agent.test_mode:
                    print(message)
                else:
                    self.agent.bot.send_message(chat_id=self.agent.chat_id, text=message)

                await asyncio.sleep(0.001)


class Messager2:

    def __init__(self, agent):
        self.agent = agent

    def create_task(self):
        return self.agent.loop.create_task(self._run_forever())

    async def _run_forever(self):
        while True:
            await self.run()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    async def run(self):
        current_time = datetime.now()
        msgs = fetch_messages_from_db(current_time)
        for _ in range(len(msgs)):
            message = "This is coroutine 1"

            if self.agent.test_mode:
                print(message)
            else:
                self.agent.bot.send_message(chat_id=self.agent.chat_id, text=message)

            await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
```

Ignore boilerplate code for now please.

**My problem is:**

The code *sometimes* runs fine when Messagers print to console and with the asyncio sleeps I've set up: `asyncio.sleep(0.1)` in `_run_forever` and `asyncio.sleep(0.001)` in `run`. But if I try to reduce `asyncio.sleep(0.1)` to `asyncio.sleep(0.01)`, then I on CTRL+C shutdown I *always* get a warning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 313, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File ".venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File ".venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/queues.py", line 359, in get
    res = self._reader.recv_bytes()
  File ".venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/connection.py", line 219, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/connection.py", line 382, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
```

I also get this warning when not running in test mode and sending live messages via Telegram, while sleeps are unchanged. This problem seems to correlate with sleep times, amount of data fetched from DB and whether I am just printing messages to console or sending them to Telegram bot. I don't know the exact relationship, I'm assuming someone a lot more familiar with multiprocessing/asyncio in Python might point out the most likely reasons based on the fact of existence of correlation itself... I'll record the observations if necessary

I've done some googling and haven't found any particular answer. There are some discussion threads on bugs.python.org blaming a bug in GC, but they all seem to be resolved in <3.8 versions.

***What might be causing this warning?***

P.S. I'm aware that fetching data from disk in a coroutine is bad and won't scale, I'm planning to fix it, I just have other things to deal with currently. But comments on other design flaws are welcome.

Comment: There are issues with asyncio.sleep(x) where x is less than the system clock resolution.  On Windows that is 15 milliseconds.  So I think that asyncio.sleep(0.01) will not actually sleep at all, whereas asyncio.sleep(0.1) will.  asyncio.sleep(0.01) will, however, cause a Task switch if there is another task to run.  Also, I doubt if you will ever get a clean shutdown of a multiprocessing program with Ctrl+C.  I always have to have an orderly termination of secondary threads/processes.

Comment: But I thought I was handling KeyboardInterrupt well by commanding process pool to terminate via multiprocessing api... I might be missing something though